# Windows server 2008 r2 DNS installation

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008-r2, domaincontroller

I have recently decided to learn a few things about the active directory, domain controller and servers in general, so I decided to install Windows server 2008 on an old machine that I found at home. However, I successfully install Active Directory Domain Settings and then after installing the DNS and rebooting, the machine stays at the Windows loading screen, then a black screen with the cursor and after that it reboots on its own, this process takes a long time.

Any ideas? Is the machine too slow for the OS with all the roles installed or am I doing something wrong?

Machine:

ESPRIMO P5905 (i945G)

CPU: Intel Celeron 3.20GHz

RAM: 1GB

HDD: 230GB

Answer (score 2):

I've checked and your system looks okay. Here is the link if you want to check too. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef8f3711-d1d1-4d4a-8a04-ee7bf6110554#BKMK_System

Microsoft says that problem solved with service pack 2. You can try it.